# A web site code can't connect to a soap service on the same server

Tags: .net, web-services, soap, web-config

My ASP.NET web site calls a .net service from a code in App_Code to retrieve some information.

The web service is hosted at `http://mydomain/ws/DirectoryService.asmx`.

Whenever I deploy a web site on any server other then the same server that the required .net service is hosted on, everything works good.

Whenever I deploy the site to the same web server, that the web service is hosted on, I get 401.1 error.

I have the following binding defined in web.config of the site:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="LR Directory ServiceSoap" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://mydomain/ws/DirectoryService.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="LR Directory ServiceSoap" contract="ExpertsServiceReference.LRDirectoryServiceSoap" name="LR Directory ServiceSoap" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Apparently, the problem lies in that binding. It can't work from within the same server. How can the problem be fixed?

P.S. If I comment out the binding in web.config, the web site loads fine, but it is not fully functional, since it can't connect to a service.

UPDATE: A very important detail: My target web site and a .net service are both located on the same server, same IIS, but are bound to a different external IP addresses, so the problem can't be in a network access field.

Also, If I set the authentication mode of the web site from Anonymous to Windows, everything works fine, but I need to provide a windows creds each time I access the site.

Comment: Hmm, `bypassProxyOnLocal="false"`?

Comment: 401.1 indicates the service is running but you can't authenticate. Are the credentials passed in correct?

Comment: @Chris - tried to set it to true - no result.

Comment: @Jeremy - it is an authentication problem - correct. There are no other credentials except for the settings in the binding. The same code works on any other server, so the problem is most likely in <security mode="None">

Comment: I see `<message clientCredentialType="UserName">`... Try Fiddler and see if you get any more detail in the 401.1 message.

Comment: I doubt Fiddler would show me any of the relevant info, since the authentication error is on the site-service segment, not on the browser-site. The IP of my site is 82.144.221.87 You can Fiddle around for a minute for yourself. The key is in the fact, that with Windows auth enabled for the site, everything works. It's like the site's identity can't access the service from localhost.

Comment: Is this a web site (File->New Web Site), or a web application project (File->New Project)?

Comment: It is a File-> New Web Site but the problem is already solved. I have described the solution in my answer below. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. It turned out that I needed to Edit an anonymous authentication settings, so that when used (in my case it is always), the code would go under application pool's identity, and not IUSR:
[image]

Comment: Authenticated anonymice.  Wow!  :-)  Sorry, this gave me a big grin.  I know you didn't mean to provide me amusement, but...

Comment: Fixed it. Although probably shouldn't have to have a funny answer for other to get a smile =)

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you are running the webservice and website on different *ports*, and make sure your configuration reflects the correct port.

If you are running two websites on the same port (by default this would be port 80, reserved for HTTP), they will conflict with each other - one of them will get the port, the other will not.

Say you change the web service port to 8080, you would configure the site to use the endpoint:

```
address="http://mydomain:8080/ws/DirectoryService.asmx"
```

Comment: Service and the site are on the same server, but are bound to different external IP's, so port can't be a problem. I have added some more info to the question body that might help. In particular, the fact about Windows Auth turning the whole thing working. So it's an authentication to the server due to binding setting problem.

Comment: @MaximV.Pavlov - What about DNS/hosts file?

Comment: Checked it. DNS resolves fine. Tried to change all the host names to ip's - same problem. As I said - if I turn on the Windows authentication for an entire site, without changing any other config, everything works. The problem is that the IIS doesn't allow an inter-appPool communication or something.