# [EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at

Tags: web-services, asp.net-mvc-4, endpoint

Error Message:
[EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at "Link/MobileMotivation.asmx" that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.]

This is a MVC4 applcation, it works fine on the local machine. However when I implement it to the server which is the same server as the web service, it shows the error message.

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="MobileMotivationSoap" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://stuiis.cms.gre.ac.uk/bb116/FinalYear2/FinalYear2/MobileMotivation.asmx"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MobileMotivationSoap"
    contract="MobileMotivationService.MobileMotivationSoap" name="MobileMotivationSoap" />
</client>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to edit the anonymous authentication settings.

Go to:

1. Server Manager
2. IIS
3. Connections > Sites > YourSite
4. Click Authentication > Enable

At this point you can select application pool identity.

More details here: [A web site code can't connect to a soap service on the same server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7987179/a-web-site-code-cant-connect-to-a-soap-service-on-the-same-server)

Comment: Thanks, I solved the problem by using IP address of the server instead of the domain name.

Comment: I'm using the Default Web Site with anonymous auth enabled, but I still have the listed problem.

Comment: IP address works for me, but it seams not so good, really hope to know the "correct" fix solution for this issue