# Windows server IIS can connect to .asmx from outside of server but not internally

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, windows-server-2008

I am trying to contact an asmx file on an asp.net web aplication hosted in IIS 7.0. If I use Soap to contact the asmx from outside the server everything works fine.

However when I run code from the server itself it does not work. The call threw a http 417 error.

Adding the following code resolves the 417 error:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
```

However after adding that the call throws a 404 error.

Additionally, if I navigate to the asmx via a browser on my local computer I get the page. If I use a browser on the server I get a 501 DNS rebind.

I am a bit lost on where to start. All ideas are welcome.

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7987179/a-web-site-code-cant-connect-to-a-soap-service-on-the-same-server

Comment: Issue looks the same but solution of anonymous authentication does not work.

Comment: `nslookup xxxx.com` returns the public or local IP? if its the public IP the request will likely route out over the internet and NAT can break this on the return leg.

Comment: nslookup returns public IP. weird thing is, the server where it is not working is a development server which is a copy of the production server. On the production server the same setup does work. nslookup on the production server also returns the public ip

Comment: Are the domain names the same? If not does the working one have a DNS entry pointing to the local address if you run a DNS server? or look in the HOSTS file, a line like `xxxx.com local.ip.address.here` would cause it to work.  (You can add that line to the dev machine's HOSTS file  and see if it works)